# Cordova iOS inapp browser does not work in iPhone 4s

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I am developing a hybrid app for iOS devices using, HTML, Javascript and cordova. It has a to open a link in an external browser window, for which we uses inapp browser. This works fine in iPhone 5s and above version devices. But it doesn't open inapp browser on iPhone5 and iPhone 4s. It does not throw any error in console.

The Inapp browser is initiated as given below.

```
 var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(response.data.url, "_blank", "location=no,toolbar=yes,closebuttoncaption=Back,toolbarposition=top,disallowoverscroll=true,presentationstyle=pagesheet,clearcache=yes"); ref.addEventListener("loadstart", function(event){
                    myFunctions.handleResult(ref, event.url);
                    fn.hideLoader();}
```

In cordova-plugin.xml

```
{
    "file": "plugins/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/www/inappbrowser.js",
    "id": "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.inappbrowser",
    "pluginId": "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser",
    "clobbers": [
        "cordova.InAppBrowser.open",
        "window.open"
    ]
},
```

Comment: Your page itself is not loading? What happens if you use window.open instead? Could be a possible certificate issue as well

Comment: @gandhi I don't think it is an issue with certificates. Because it works fine on iPhone 5s and above versions. The issue is like when trying to open Inapp browser, first it shows the loader, and then the loader fades away and nothing has happened with Inapp browser

Comment: Did you inspect device for console errors using chrome inspect devices option?

Comment: I have checked the console using Mac inspector. There's nothing wrong actually in the console. It's clear.

Comment: Did you tried simple window.open instead?